# Deploying charm from local host

Tags: juju

I'm trying to deploy vanilla charm as i'm beginner in writing charm, I'm facing following issues in this regard.
I run this

```
charm proof .
```

and I got following output:

```
I: display-name not provided, add for custom naming in the UI
W: no copyright file
I: missing recommended hook config-changed
```

Secondly, when I try to run

```
juju debug-log
```

I get this error:

```
unit-mysql-1: 16:07:04 ERROR juju.worker.uniter.operation hook "db-relation-joined" failed: exit status 1
```

Can anyone help me in resolving these issues?